# What is the core Difference between Runtime Headers and just "Headers"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, header, cydia

I'm in process of making a new iOS tweak. I grabbed iOS Headers https://github.com/MP0w/iOS-Headers.
Later on I figured out another repository on Github named iOS Runtime Headers https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers

Now i'm confused. What is the difference between these two?

Comment: Those are both bad links.

Comment: I figured it out and fixed the links.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 main sources for headers: from the developer of the code, from class-dump, and from a runtime header dumping tool.

1. Apple or SDK developers will release a header file that includes the public interface they intend other developers to use. It might not include some methods/variable declarations they don't want you to see. UIView.h from Apple's SDK would be a great example of something they're hiding certain info from.
2. Just because they didn't include those methods in the header file, doesn't mean that instances of those classes can't respond to them. This is where a tool like class-dump comes in, which looks through the compiled Mach-O files to determine which methods/ivars the class contains, and generate a header according to that.
3. Entirely new classes, methods, and ivars can be added to removed during runtime, using Objective-C's runtime features. Things like categories that get loaded from other SDKs/object files won't appear in a class-dump of the original class either. For these reasons, runtime dumping tools can see what instances of these classes can actually respond to during runtime.

Each set of headers can be useful in determining the intended and unintended uses for a class, knowing the differences can help you get a clearer picture of whatever you're reverse engineering.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what the differences are. They are both sets of headers generated with runtime introspection. The first one says it's headers both public and private.

Just so everybody understands, both links point to sets of headers that give you access to private OS APIs. Using these will get you rejected from the app store. They're only really useful for developing apps for the developer's personal use, or for jailbroken development.